# Lagging input in ReactJS for large json structures

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react, I'm creating a form for a JSON object. I have a large JSON object that is of the structure:

```
{
  "prop1": {
    "someProp": {
      "value": 2,
      "metadata": {
        "somemetadata": "somevalue"
      }
    }
  },
  "prop2": {
    "someOtherProp": {
      "value": 3,
      "metadata": {
        "editable": true
      }
    }
  },
...otherProps
}
```

Each top level property of the object needs to appear as a tab in a form which displays all its sub-properties as editable field which I've created

```
Object.keys(object[tab]).map((key, i) => {
  <TextField value={object[tab][key].value} onChange={handler(tab, key} />
})

//handler function
const handler = (tab,key) => e => {
  object[tab][key].value = e.target.value;

  //using redux action:
  setDataObject({...object});
}
```

The problem here is, as the json structure is quite large, the onChange re-render becomes very slow. Debouncing the input hasn't really helped. I would like to know the best way to make the inputs quicker.

One way that I'd like to try is use `refs` in React but I'm not sure how I can dynamically create them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using class or function component ?

Comment: @MohamedRamrami - function components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `key` field to your `TextField`, your app will only re-render the stuff that it needs to. Something like this:

```
Object.keys(object[tab]).map((key, i) => {
  <TextField key={`${i}_${object[tab][key].value}`} value={object[tab][key].value} onChange={handler} />
})
```